# Excel 2010 autofill option by entering last four digits of 10 digit number how to

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, excel-auto-fill

I'm having list of 1000 numbers (10 digits) in each rows, need to get(retrieve) that particular number from that data by entering last four digits alone..

Just I have to retrieve the 10 digits by simply enter last 4 digits in another rows

Ps :

```
Column A
123456
456756
556678
```

Column B :
If I enter last three digits from row A, column should be automatically auto fill

- 456 should come as 123456
- 756 should come as 456756
- 678 should come as 556678

Comment: Use the search function

Comment: In my opinion, VLOOKUP with "*" symbol can help you, but I also suggest you provide the sample about this problem.

Comment: You need VBA, if you want to enter partial data in a cell, then replace that same cell with the full entry. Functions may work if want to enter the partial data in one cell, then have another cell give you the full entry. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tricks to retrieve a full number based on a partial set of digits.  Say we have 10 digit values in column **A** from **A1** through **A22**.  Say we want to retrieve one of these based on the last three digits *(which we place in cell **B1**)*

In **C1** enter the *array formula*:

```
=INDEX(A1:A22,MATCH(TEXT(B1,"General"),RIGHT(A1:A22,3),0))
```

[image]

The tricks are:

1. because we are using `RIGHT` inside `MATCH`, we need an array formula.
2. **Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.
3. because `RIGHT` returns *Text*, we must convert **B1** into *Text* using the `TEXT` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! It's working